# how to show open/close values/text in androidplot candlestick chart

Tags: android, androidplot, candlestick-chart

I'm using candlestick chart of androidplot library.meeting problems to show open and close values/labels alongwith the sticks.Here is the solution i found.

```
 final LineAndPointFormatter lpf = new LineAndPointFormatter(null, null, null, null);
    PointLabelFormatter pointLabelFormatter=new PointLabelFormatter();
   // pointLabelFormatter.hOffset=150;
    //pointLabelFormatter.vOffset=50;
    lpf.setPointLabelFormatter(pointLabelFormatter);

    plot.addSeries(openVals, lpf);

    LineAndPointFormatter lpf1 = new LineAndPointFormatter(null, null, null, null);
    PointLabelFormatter pointLabelFormatter1=new PointLabelFormatter();

    //set the vertical offset
    pointLabelFormatter1.vOffset=40;
    lpf1.setPointLabelFormatter(pointLabelFormatter1);

    plot.addSeries(closeVals,lpf1);
    CandlestickFormatter formatter = new CandlestickFormatter();

    formatter.setBodyStyle(CandlestickFormatter.BodyStyle.Square);
    formatter.setLowerCapWidth(50);
    // add the candlestick series data to the plot:
    CandlestickMaker.make(plot, formatter,
            openVals, closeVals, highVals, lowVals);
```

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?  Also would be helpful to see more of the code, particularly the CandlestickFormatter, etc. stuff.

Comment: Hi Nick. sorry for the less explaination. i found the solution by exploring the PointLabelFormatter class. we can set vertical and horizontal offsets for the open/close values. edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Nice!  One thing you might consider is tweaking it to use dp instead of pixels, to maintain consistency across devices:   formatter.vOffset = PixelUtils.dpToPix(40);

Comment: thanks i will consider this :)

Comment: hi nick.. can we change the color of the candlesticks based on custom conditions like right now we can set the color for either fallingBody or risingBody.

Comment: for the moment you might need to extend CandlestickRenderer.  or you can wait for the upcoming 1.0 release of Androidplot, which will have a more full featured implementation.

Comment: i tried extending the CandlestickRenderer. can you just guide me where can i put my condition.

 class myRenderer extends CandlestickRenderer{
        public myRenderer(XYPlot plot) {
            super(plot);
        }

        @Override
        public Formatter getFormatter(Series series) {
            return super.getFormatter(series);
        }
    }

Comment: Most straightforward approach would probably be to override drawValue(...), do your check and then adjust the passed in Formatter instance with the color(s) you want to use and then call back to super.drawValue(...).

Comment: thanks it worked :) can we change the text color of points also in the same way i.e on custom condition..??